# redirection from old urls to new urls

Tags: python, django, web

Hello everyone I want to redirect URLs like this
from
https://www.example.co.uk/pages/terms-conditions
to
https://www.example.co.uk/terms-conditions
I developed the updated site using the Django framework and now want to redirect old site URLs to new URLs and not losing traffic. what is the best way of doing…?

New site is not published it is on local machine

my [view.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t67ZC.png)

my [urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFR1Y.png)

Comment: Show your **urls.py** I want to see the setup.

Comment: @Lewis l added above lets have a look

Comment: @HassanSajjad I can't see your /terms-conditions and pages/terms-conditions endpoints.

Comment: @naheliegend let's have a look now I added

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not best practice but you can just redirect the user to the right url if he hits the other one in your views.py like:

```
def old_view(request):
   return redirect('https://www.example.co.uk/terms-conditions')

def new_view(request):
   return render(request, "your_app/conditions.html")
```

with urls.py like:

```
path('pages/terms-conditions/', views.old_view, name='old_view')
path('terms-conditions/', views.new_view, name='new_view')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the application name from the urls. In your project's **urls.py** NOT your applications **urls.py**. You should have a line similar to the following:

```
path('pages/', include('pages.urls', namespace='pages')),
```

replace the `'pages/'` with just `''`.

> *Note: Using the `pages/` allows you to provide segregation between your applications to ensure the urls do not conflict*